# Keep columns after a groupby in an empty dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

The dataframe is an empty df after query.when groupby,raise runtime waring,then get another empty dataframe with no columns.How to keep the columns?

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["PlatformCategory","Platform","ResClassName","Amount"])
print df
```

result:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [PlatformCategory, Platform, ResClassName, Amount]
Index: []
```

then groupby:

```
df = df.groupby(["PlatformCategory","Platform","ResClassName"]).sum()
df = df.reset_index(drop=False,inplace=True)
print df
```

result:
sometimes is None
sometime is empty dataframe

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []
```

why empty dataframe has no columns.

runtimewaring:

```
/data/pyrun/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby.py:3672: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log
```

if alpha + beta * ngroups < count * np.log(count):

```
/data/pyrun/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby.py:3672: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
  if alpha + beta * ngroups < count * np.log(count):
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need `as_index=False` and `group_keys=False`:

```
df = df.groupby(["PlatformCategory","Platform","ResClassName"], as_index=False).count()
df

Empty DataFrame
Columns: [PlatformCategory, Platform, ResClassName, Amount]
Index: []
```

No need to reset your index afterwards.

Comment: This was exactly what I was also looking for. Thanks a lot!

Comment: This only works for empty dataframe.In no empty dataframe case,it does't work.When  change count() to sum() ,it does't work too.I want to get the sum compatible two cases .Have you some advice?

Comment: @user2890059 Share some data... in your question?

Comment: @user2890059 If you are trying to find the sum of some particular column, then call sum() on that column.

Comment: change to sum,get empty dataframe without columns

Comment: @user2890059 Interestingly, I don't think it's possible to do this with sum, because sum condenses all rows in an aggregation attempt. Try it with actual data and you'll understand.

Answer (score 1):

Some code that works the same for `.sum()` whether or not the dataframe is empty:

```
def groupby_sum(df, groupby_cols):
    groupby = df.groupby(groupby_cols, as_index=False)
    summed = groupby.sum()
    return (groupby.count() if summed.empty else summed).set_index(groupby_cols)

df = groupby_sum(df, ["PlatformCategory", "Platform", "ResClassName"])
```