# Apply Groupby on a resulting empty dataframe which is a result of filter

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

A sample dataframe as mentioned below:

```
df_A = pd.DataFrame({'field1':[1,2,3,4,5], 'field2':[11,12,13,14,15], 'field3':[c1,c2,c3,c4,c5], 'field4':[m1,m2,m3,m4,m5], 'field5':[21,22,23,24,25], 'field6':[f1,f2,f3,f4,f5], 'field7':[31,32,33,34,35]})
```

I have a logic as mentioned below:

```
df_A['field7'] = df_A[(df_A['filed4']== 'abc') & (df_A['field5']== 'def')].groupby(['field1', 'field2','field3'], as_index=False)[['field6']].transform('count')
```

but in some scenarios the filter might yield no values and I am getting the following error:

```
ValueError: No objects to concatenate
```

Though I partially understand what the error is, I am not able to get the null value column as my expected answer(Example 
 to apply groupby on an empty dataframe: [Keep columns after a groupby in an empty dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46090386/keep-columns-after-a-groupby-in-an-empty-dataframe))

Kindly let me know if I was wrong in any sense and Thanks in advance!

Edit: Added an example dataframe for the above mentioned case

Comment: For me it working nice in pandas `0.23.4`

Comment: I have 0.23.0... I'll update the version and check the results. Hope it'll not break anything. Thanks for the confirmation @jezrael

Comment: I'm still facing the same error in 0.23.4

Comment: If change `[['field6']]` to `['field6']` same problem?

Comment: yes. It's still the same issue

Comment: Yes. Also I tried with .count() instead of .transform('count) and I got the error `Wrong number of items passed 4, placement implies 1`

Comment: Tested with `df_A = pd.DataFrame({
        'field4':list('abcdef'),
         'field1':[4] * 6,
         'field2':[4] * 6,
         'field3':[4] * 6,
         'field6':[4] * 6,
         'field5':list('aaabbb')
})` and no problem

Comment: @ManikanthaNekkalapudi, Please provide a **[mcve]**. In this case, that requires a sample of your dataframe which demonstrates the problem. If you need help with this, see [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples).

Comment: I'm confused between `.count()` and `transform('count')`. When filter result is empty DataFrame,  `[[field6]].count()` __(with double square brackets)__ is working fine but not `transform('count')` and vice-versa if filter result is **NOT** empty DataFrame. Am I missing something here?