# Pandas groupby on empty DataFrame results in no columns

Tags: python, pandas, apply

I have an empty DataFrame with columns but no rows. 
I want to apply groupby on it but it results in no columns. 
How to apply groupby and keep columns?

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'a':[], 'b': []})
df = df.groupby('a').apply(lambda g: g).reset_index(drop=True)
```

output:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []
```

df.index

```
Float64Index([], dtype='float64', name='a')
```

Comment: what is dk ? and why you need apply function to empty dataframe ?

Comment: I realize I can make some logic to check if df is empty but I want to avoid it for a reason. I am after why I loose columns here?

Comment: related : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46090386/keep-columns-after-a-groupby-in-an-empty-dataframe

Comment: @anky_91 I think the answer there covers this question.  Voting as duplicate.

Comment: @r.ook no, the question in the URL provided remains unanswered as the extra argument does not solve the problem. I read that question before I submitted my question here. Ty that solution and see if it works if you think it answers the question I asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For pandas **1.1.0** please use

```
df.groupby('a', as_index=False).aggregate(lambda g: g)
```

output:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [a, b]
Index: []
```